# What to put for hubCallback for youtube-notifaction api

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-notification to get new uploads for my discord bot.
I'm not sure what to put for the urlCallback section?

This is the example code:

```
const notifier = new YouTubeNotifier({
  hubCallback: 'https://example.com/youtube',
  port: 8080,
  secret: 'Something',
  path: '/youtube'
});
notifier.setup();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the documentation for the package makes it pretty clear

Quoting it

> **YouTubeNotifier.constructor(options)**
> options is an object that you may write your own properties to. The following properties are read by YouTubeNotifier:
>
> - **hubCallback** - Your ip/domain name that will be used as a callback URL by Pubsubhubbub. It must be in a URL format, ex: 'https://example.com/'. This is a required property as the default is undefined.

So basically your callback will be your localhost kinda thing, where the server will get data from. If you have let's say on a Repl in Repl.it, then it will have to get the data from the Repl hosting URL